# My laptop isn't shutting down.How to resolve this?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, shutdown

I actually dual booted my laptop to install ubuntu 18.04. My laptop is an HP laptop with windows 10 operating system as default.But,after installing, I am unable to shutdown my laptop from windwos interface using the shutdown option at the bottom left icon of windows.Everytime I shutdown,it restarts.But,when I switch over to ubuntu I am able to shutdown my laptop.Also,after partitioning Imy douments in windows didn't loose.They are as it is.Could anyone help me to fix this issue?Thanks in advance.I tried troubleshooting as well.Also,I tried to restore the default plan settings in the edit power plan option.But,none of them worked actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this would be a result of Fast Startup enabled.

Switch it off from the Power Options in Windows. If I am not wrong, some laptops have a similar setting (not same) enabled in BIOS as Fast Boot. For dual booting it is advisable to switch that off too.

For disabling fast startup, follow these [solution 1 steps](https://appuals.com/windows-10-restarts-instead-of-shutting-down/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Shutdown%20settings%20section,not%20restart%20on%20its%20own.)

For disabling fast boot, you'll have to access bios, find the the Fast Boot and disable it, then save and exit.
Now I am not sure how to access the BIOS on HP machines but it is usually one of F10, F2, F12, F1, or DEL.

Comment: Thankyou so much..I think this worked.But,since I didn't do this while dual booting,will that cause any other problem in my laptop?

Comment: It should not. What this does is to simply reduce the time required by Windows and, Windows only, to boot by saving some data (not a computer science background, so don't know the technicality). Anyway having a windows specific setting during bootup is bound to clash with windows. Tbh it does not have much to do with Linux